# TV Output ModX Revolution

Tags: modx

So I have a chunk:

```
<li> [[+img-port]]
          <div class="floater">
            <h2>[[+longtitle]]</h2>
            <p>[[+introtext]]</p>
            <p class="readmore"><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" title="Read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </li>
```

And a TV-parameter "img-port" input: image, output: image.
I've selected an image for every my document. But when I place a chunk into my webpage everythig is fine, but Image. I see longtitle, introtex, but Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a getResources template chunk? Then you have to enable TV processing with "&processTVs=`1`" (see docs).

Comment: I use Ditto for this chunk [[Ditto? &processTVs=1 &tpl=`PortfolioSlide-tpl` &startID=`8` &sortDir=`ASC` ]]

Comment: For Revo the MODx team recommend getResources as Ditto won't be supported.http://modxcms.com/extras/package/96 . Have you tried getResources, you might get more support on the forums this way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you inspect the rendered HTML using Firebug or just even "View Source". Is there possible a problem with the image path?

Comment: [[Ditto? &tpl=`PortfolioSlide-tpl` &startID=`8` &sortDir=`ASC` ]]